# SOCKS 5 Server - BND.PORT & BND.ADDR

Tags: socks

In C++ (I didn't include code because this is more of a protocol understanding matter) I am creating a SOCKS5 server and had a few questions because the client terminates the connection after I send it the approved message. In the RFC it says BND.ADDR and BND.PORT are used for:   [RFC 1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt)

> o  BND.ADDR       server bound address
>
> o BND.PORT       server bound
>   port in network octet order`
>
> In the reply to a CONNECT, BND.PORT contains the port number that the 
>   server assigned to connect to the target host, while BND.ADDR
>   contains the associated IP address.

Here are my questions,

1. What is BND.PORT and what should I specify for it?.
2. What does it mean by "server assigned to connect to the target host" Is target host the "Client"?

   3. I've read the RFC front to back like 5 times and I have yet to understand it, can someone go into more detail about the BND.PORT and what it means?

I was sniffing around in Wireshark and I found that BND.PORT was different for each request made. (I am not sure what port to enter because everything I tried resulted in Proxifer (The socks client) says "The server gave an unexpected replay - Connection terminated"

Wireshark connection hex-dump from an actual SOCKS5 server (not mine):
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's so hard to read your hand write words.

Answer (score 5):

Just to make sure we're on the same page... This is the relationship between client, server and host. Notice that the client and host can't talk to each other directly.

CLIENT <-> SERVER <-> HOST

> What does it mean by "server assigned to connect to the target host" Is target host the "Client"?

No. The "host" is the device the client is trying to connect to via the SOCKS5 server. The "client" is on the other side of the SOCKS5 server, furthest away from the host.

> What is BND.PORT and what should I specify for it?.

BND.PORT is the source port of packets leaving the SOCKS5 server, bound for a host. You have no control over what port the server chooses. Think about it. Where does a host see packets coming from? It certainly isn't the client. From the perspective of the host, packets are all coming from the server, it doesn't know about the client. Additionally the BND.ADDR is the IP of the server.

What I've said is true under the condition that CONNECT is being used. I have no experience with BIND or UDP ASSOCIATE yet.

Comment: Hey I forgot to update this but after reading the rfc I found its just reserved for which port/IP I used to handle the request. The real problem I was having was sending an extra character which was causing the issue

Comment: What are BND.ADDR and BND.PORT used for for the client? I see they usually are 0.0.0.0:00. So what's the meaning of the two value ?